# Hibernate Bidirectional mapping is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 entities for two tables. Student has one to many relationship with MonthAttendance. student_id is the join colum. Please look at the below code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="student_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String studentId;
/*
*More codes
*/

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MonthAttendance> monthAttendances;
/*
*mutators
*getter and setter methods
*/

}


@Entity
@Table(name="month_attendance")
public class MonthAttendance implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="month_year_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String monthYearId;
/*
*More codes
*/
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;
/*
*mutators
*getter and setter methods
*/
}
```

I have DAO class to get the student data from database. I used below code to fetch the data,

```
List<Student> studentList = session.createQuery("from Student").list();
List<Student> studentList = session.createQuery("from MonthAttendance").list();
```

Both are working fine. But the object has a recursive structure like Student has MonthAttendance, MonthAttendance has Student, again Student has MonthAttendance and goes on.
is there any way to resolve this? I just need a Student has MonthAttendance which doesn't have student, if i try to get Student. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of this recursive behavior just remove the:

```
cascade = CascadeType.ALL
```

from Student entity, like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
private Set<MonthAttendance> monthAttendances;
```

Cascade basically tells this:

If I perform an action on an entity, how should I act regarding the associated entity.

Should I perform that same action on it?

Let's take your example:

If I'll try to save/persist a `MonthAttendance` object, Hibernate will try to do save/persist operation on the `Student` object related to it as well. Why?

Because on `MonthAttendance` entity under the `Student` association, we have CascadeType.ALL (under CascadeType.ALL we have 4 to 5 kind of actions) which means whenever you try to save/persist `MonthAttendance` Hibernate tries to do the same action (save/persist in our case) on the attached `Student` object.

That explains why you get this recursive behavior because you marked both sides of the association with:

```
cascade = CascadeType.ALL
```

When you save the first entity it tries to save the the second, and the second try to save the first again and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Removed the "cascade = CascadeType.ALL" from the student entity. But still facing the same problem

Comment: Can you post your stack trace with the exception?

Comment: I'm not getting any exception. Student have a set of MonthAttendance, MonthAttendance has Student objects, when retrieving data. 
So i'm getting the below exception, when converting my result into json,

Comment: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.WriterBasedGenerator._writeString(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.WriterBasedGenerator._writeFieldName(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonGeneratorBase.writeFieldName(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter$StdMethod.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:214)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:58)

Comment: So i just to want a Student object which has the set of MonthAttendence, But MonthAttendance will never have Student object, as we get in Unidirectional mapping. I'm not sure whether it's possible or not.

So Why i used bidirectional mapping instead of unidirectional mapping is that, sometimes i may need to fetch MonthAttendance along with Student, in this case student should not have MonthAttendance set. Because it'll end up in the same problem.

This may be little confusing. I'm not sure we have any option to do this or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you elaborate how json is related to your case.

Comment: {"students : ":[{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":{"monthAttendances":[{"student":........

Comment: This is not helpful. Have best of luck.